# Different behavior when running ls from within a script

Tags: bash, ls

I want to rename a couple of file named in an enumerated way. My previous approach was to use this command line:

```
FILES=`ls "someDir/"`; for f in $FILES; do echo "Processing file: $f"; done;
```

`Echoing` the filename is just for demo purposes. The above produces the expected output:

```
Processing file: File1
Processing file: File2
Processing file: File3
...
```

However when I run (what I thought is the same thing) the below script, it treats the whole `ls` output as one file and produces this output:

```
SCRIPT:
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`ls "someDir/"`

for f in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing file: $f"
done

OUTPUT:
Processing file: File1
File2
File3
...
```

I can't get my head around it. Also I'm not even sure wether it is `ls` which is producing this behavior.
What is causing this behavior? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs),  and rather use [process-substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to process command output.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "$file"
    # Do whatever you want to do with your file here
done < <(find someDir/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0 | sort -z)
```

The above simple `find` lists all files from the required directory (including ones with spaces/special-characters). Here, the output of `find` command is fed to `stdin` which is parsed by `while-loop`.

To ordered sorting of files, add a `sort -z` piped to the `find` command output.

Comment: Is there a way to tell `find` to keep the actual order of the files? Since I need them to be processed in the order they are named in. So `File1` first, then `File2` and so on. But `find` produces a miss ordered output like `File325`, `File3`, `File20`, ... .